# Чтение JSON файла D3.JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

В примерах в документации к D3 дан такой код для загрузки данных из json

```
  d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
   if (error) throw error;
   ...
   })
```

Я получаю ошибку :

```
d3.v2.js:2936 GET http://127.0.0.1:7979/graph/BuildGraph/data.json 500
```

файл data.json лежит в той же директории что и скрипт

В чем тут подвох ? Наверное я что то не понимаю о загрузке json в js

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var result = request.response;
}
```

удаленные запросы по протоколaм http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https загружает нормально, но если файл расположен локально не не получается

Comment: если в браузере это открыть - все ок? так то 500 это обычно ошибка сервера

Comment: `d3.v2` очень уж старая версия либы у Вас, но это не суть =)

Comment: что открыть в браузере? я дополнил вопрос)

Comment: тот же запрос что вы делаете из js ` http://127.0.0.1:7979/graph/BuildGraph/data.json`

Comment: Ошибка. У меня django - приложение и этот url не обрабатываю. Я правильно понимаю что нужно написать обработчик на этот адрес ?

Comment: Я кажется понял, а какой Вы используете веб сервер? как Вы открываете страницу в браузере?

Comment: в общем необходимо чтобы сервер, в случае когда у него запросили ресурс по этому адресу, отдал его, иначе вряд ли что-то получится, и это никак не относится к js

Comment: Логично, спасибо, щас буду пробовать.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо

Comment: ну и отлично, пожалуйста